# Adding external javascript files to magento header

Tags: magento, php

I am trying to add some external javascript files to the magento cms but somehow they don't seem to work, though they display alright in the head section.

I am adding following lines of code to the **head.phtml**

```
<!--pankaj js edition-->

<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>jQuery_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl(); ?>Common_1205141001.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

They are showing in the head section when the page is rendered, but doesn't seem to do the work they are supposed to be the doing.

Am, I doing something wrong. Because the files work well in simple html page. Do i need to add the files somewhere else. Sorry to bother but i am a newbie for magento.

Comment: Maybe `jquery.min.js` needs to be loaded _before_ the other two?

Comment: @JürgenThelen , absolutely correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be 2 issues with this

1) You are attempting to execute jquery in jQuery_1205141001.js which is included in the first line, where as you are including the jquery library later
2) Your jquery is conflicting with prototype. For this you need to add this in the phtml before you execute any jquery code and after including jquery library

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

and then use $j.function instead of $.function for jquery
e.g.

```
$j(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {

  if (event.keyCode == 37) {

    $j('#prev1').click();
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    $j('#next1').click();
  }
});
```

instead of

```
$(document.documentElement).keyup(function (event) {

  if (event.keyCode == 37) {

    $('#prev1').click();
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    $('#next1').click();
  }
});
```

Comment: Good solution.  I would further add, however, that adding jquery to Magento is a bad decision.  It already uses prototype, so adding a second javascript library bulks up the code for no good reason.

Comment: jQuery has a lot more visibility and community support than prototype. Haven't seen people using prototype in independent projects much.

Comment: I wish Magento did use JQuery - hopefully they will in future as jQuery seems to be becomming the web standard.  However, my point still stands : 2 javascript libraries is bulky for no reason, and causes conflicts issues.  You can't remove Prototype from Magento, so it seems the best choice is to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than editing the head.phtml file directly to add your JS referecnces you should really place it in to your themes local.xml like so:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="google.cdn.jquery" after="-">
        <action method="setText">
            <text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/jQuery_1205141001.js</script></action>
</reference>
```

Also check for Javascript errors with Firebug. If there are javascript errors that are causing some js functionality to fail firebug will tell you this.

Comment: Just thinking a little more you may need to actually need to alter your themes head.phtml to call  getChildHtml() BEFORE getCssJsHtml() in order for the external JS (Google hosted jQuery)to be called before the remaining JS.

Comment: this doesn't work. I had that problem yesterday. Adding it to local.xml load the js last. So if you by any change have a jquery reference in any other module, won't work.

Comment: True but see my comment above about swapping getChildHtml() & getCssJsHtml().

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs"><script>[MODULE]/your.js</script></action>

    </reference>
```

create folder with same as your module name in js folder of magento root and copy your js file in this folder.