# jquery header bars in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I am developing small mobile app which requires a header in the page. I am using html5 with below code but i did not get header and theme also not working. My code is mentioned below

Script:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="OptionsMenu.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="stylesheet" src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

Html:

```
<div data-role="header"  data-theme="b">
            <h1>
              Gps Coordinates
            </h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: did you stored those headers in local? did you included those js files in js directory?

Comment: Yes I included all the js files in same folder where my html file is located.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Comment: add 'js/' before your source.

Comment: Thanks for replay, But There are no sub folder for js files all are in same folder (Html and js files). So /js is not required right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10718530/2567813 refer this

Comment: add jquery mobile ref after core jquery

Answer (score 0):

did you followed the pattern of devloping a proper mobile app page?
like :

```
 <div data-role="page" class="jqm-boilerplate">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="jqm-header" data-tap-toggle="false" >
                <!-- main header -->
                </div>
        <div role="main" class="ui-content jqm-content"
                data-overlay-theme="a">
                </div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"
                data-theme="e" style="position: fixed;">
                </div>
 </div>
```

Can you create a jsfiddle for your code???????
Are the paths for jquery-mobile css correct??